# PHP MySQLI DateTime TimeStamps not pulling correctly

Tags: php, datetime, mysqli

OK! So, I have a page where I'm trying to pull a list of records from the database with dates < 30 days from expiration.
Now, the tricky part is - that the date format is in "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"

Here's my code:

```
$Today = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(ExpireDate, '$Today') < 30 ORDER BY `StartDate` ASC")) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //show records
        //this type of query usually works when I'm NOT doing stuff with dates
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

When I try to pull just records without any date/time conditions, it gives me the entire list of records, but when I want to see the those conditions, it doesn't display anything.

How do I show the records that are 30 days from expiration?

**I SHOULD NOTE - that this is for internal use, only, and that there is no access from the outside world.**

(I just wanted something simple for internal records keeping)

I've even tried this:

```
select * from table where some_date < curdate() - interval 30 day
```

and failed miserably... thoughts?

Comment: exactly 30 days? or anything under 30 days? for instance 16 days and 29 days in the same resultset?

Comment: Is the `expireDate` column a datetime column?

Comment: @iam-decoder "< = 30"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the `>` & `<` operators take care of it

```
$Today = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$ExpiresFromToday= date("Y-m-d h:i:s", strtotime("+30 days"));
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`ExpireDate` < '$ExpiresFromToday' AND `ExpireDate` > '$Today') ORDER BY `StartDate` ASC")){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //show records
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

**EDIT**

to work with `DATEDIFF` tell mysql to treat the datetime string as a date:

```
$Today = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (DATEDIFF(DATE(`ExpireDate`), DATE('$Today')) < 30 AND `ExpireDate` >= '$Today') ORDER BY `StartDate` ASC")){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        //show records
    }
    mysqli_close($mysqli);
}
```

Comment: @iam-decoder BOTH of those suggestions worked out nicely!  Thanks!